# Strange errors and tried reinstalling open cv and face_recognition and still get errors tried all kinds from this site and nothing has worked

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pip

I got 2 errors while trying to install pip3 install face_recognition command failed building wheel for dlib and failed building wheel for face-recognition models on linux

> Failed building wheel for face-recognition-models
> Failed building wheel for dlib

Then it said it was successful face-recognotion-1 instead of without the 1 and scripts using module face_recognition still fails! How do I purge all opencv and face_recog and start again from scratch?

import face_recognition

The strangest error I'm not even trying to run that file as you can see but its referring to it like it depends onit

```
./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "/home/jay/Documents/Scripts/PYTHON/Face_Recognition/Newest_2021/face_recognition_examples/face_recognition.py", line 14, in <module>
    face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
```

I need to purge it all and start again without reinstalling the os how do U guarantee a fix for this issue please?

I'm on linux mint using python3

Any ideas?

I want to purge everything to do with opencv cmake pip face_recognition completely so it all can be done from the start without wiping the whole os.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with

```
#!/bin/bash
# (c)J~Net 2021
# jnet.sytes.net
#
# Use sudo or give exec perms! sudo chmod +x *.sh
# sudo -H ./reinstall.sh
# USE @ YOUR OWN RISK! I ACCEPT NO LIABILITY FOR ANY DAMAGE CAUSED TO YOUR OS!
#
echo "Uninstalling Face Recog & Dlib"
echo ""
sudo pip3 uninstall face_recognition -y
sudo pip3 uninstall dlib -y
sudo pip2 uninstall face_recognition -y
sudo pip2 uninstall dlib -y
sudo pip uninstall face_recognition -y
sudo pip uninstall dlib -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove face_recognition
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove opencv
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove cmake
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove dlib
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python-opencv
#
echo "Now Reinstalling For Python3 for use with OpenCV By J~Net 2021"
echo "Please, wait, this will take some time do not use computer for anything while its working!"
echo ""
sudo apt install -y cmake
#
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
#
cd dlib
mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; cmake --build .
#
cd ..
python3 setup.py install
pip3 install face_recognition
#
sudo apt install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config
sudo apt install -y libjpeg8-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
sudo apt install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt install -y libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
sudo apt install -y libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt install -y libatlas-base-dev gfortran
sudo apt install -y python2.7-dev python3.5-dev
sudo apt install -y libx11-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libopencv-dev build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python-dev python-numpy libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev libtbb-dev libqt4-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils unzip
#
mkdir opencv
cd opencv
wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip -O opencv-3.2.0.zip
unzip opencv-3.2.0.zip
cd opencv-3.2.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
echo ""
echo "Setup Complete!"
echo ""
echo ""
echo "Reinstall Complete!"
echo ""
```

Comment: Also make sure you dont have any files with simular names to modules python is using!